# Máscará jQuery não funciona no elemento duplicado - mesma classe, mesmo id

Tags: jquery, html, jsfiddle

Estou utilizando a opção de máscara [jQuery-Mask-Plugin](https://github.com/igorescobar/jQuery-Mask-Plugin) e utilizo um código de duplicação de campos; entretanto, ao duplicar o elemto, a máscara não acompanha, ou seja, o novo elemento (duplicado) não traz a máscara do elemento de origem.

Alguma ideia de como fazer um *reload* no jQuery para que a máscara seja aplicada?

Segue o fiddle:

[jsFiddle - Duplica Campos](http://jsfiddle.net/evertramos/ag9p2tvj/8/)

Código da Máscara:

```
    var maskBehavior = function (val) {
  return val.replace(/\D/g, '').length === 11 ? '(00) 00000-0000' : '(00) 0000-00009';
},
options = {onKeyPress: function(val, e, field, options) {
        field.mask(maskBehavior.apply({}, arguments), options);
    }
};

$('.phone').mask(maskBehavior, options);
```

Código jQuery de duplicação do campo:

```
$(document).ready(function (){
    clone_obj = function(obj_name, obj_destination) {
        $('#' + obj_name).clone().appendTo('#' + obj_destination).find("input[type='text']").val('');        
    }

    delete_obj = function(obj_name, group) {
        $(obj_name).closest('#' + group).remove();        
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma dica e vc mudar o ID para cada novo campo adicionado... porém o problema não é este.
Vc precisa aplicar novamente a mascara para cada novo campo criado, ou seja, toda vez que um novo elemento for criado vc te que aplicar:  **$('#NOVOID').mask(maskBehavior, options);**

Eu alterei um trecho do seu codigo para: http://jsfiddle.net/ag9p2tvj/10/

```
 clone_obj = function(obj_name, obj_destination) {
        $('#' + obj_name).clone().appendTo('#' + obj_destination).find("input[type='text']").val('');
       $('.phone').mask(maskBehavior, options);        
    }
```

Não sei se por pegar o elemento pela Class  vai dar algum problema... mas desta forma tb funciona.

Comment: Excelente! Obrigado, resolveu o problema. Abs!

Comment: Alterei seu post com o novo jsFiddle, ok?

Comment: Acabei de colocar tb... mas valeu!!!